# Is there a possibility to reorder a chart in altair based on a selection?

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart that is resortable based on user input. I know how to create the selection, but I don't think the expression is reevaluated when the input dropdown changes. Maybe this just isn't possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from io import StringIO
TESTDATA = StringIO("""Nom du film,Synopsis,Son,Décors et Costumes,Qualité tournage,Qualité montage,Jeu des acteurs,Bonus,TOTAL
Chaque seconde compte,6.0,6.0,6.67,6.33,7.17,6.5,0.67,7.17
Premier Rôle,7.5,7.0,7.5,8.0,7.5,7.0,0.0,7.5
Diagnostic,6.17,3.67,5.5,5.67,6.33,5.67,0.17,5.67
The Last Name of John Cage,6.0,6.75,4.75,5.75,5.5,5.25,0.5,6.25
Photos Souvenirs,6.17,4.67,6.17,5.83,5.5,4.67,0.17,5.5""")
df_test = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")

value = 'value'
synopsis = 'Synopsis'
sound = 'Son'
costumes = 'Décors et Costumes'
tournage = 'Qualité tournage'
montage = 'Qualité montage'
acteurs = 'Jeu des acteurs'
bonus = 'Bonus'

fields = [synopsis,sound,costumes,tournage,montage,acteurs,bonus]

input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=fields)
sort_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['score'], bind=input_dropdown, name='Score to sort by ', init={'score': 'value'})

legend_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['column'], bind='legend')

bar_chart = alt.Chart(df_test).transform_fold(fields, as_=['column', 'value']).mark_bar(size=10).encode(
        x=alt.X('Nom du film:N',sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='value', op='average', order='descending')),
        y=alt.Y('value:Q'),
        color=alt.Color('column:N', legend=alt.Legend(orient="left")),
        tooltip=fields,
    ).properties(width=alt.Step(12)).add_selection(sort_selection, legend_selection)

bar_chart
```

If it is possible, how could I achieve that?

[stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIuZg.png)

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data or recreate the issue using a sample dataset? This will facilitate for those trying to answer your question.

Comment: @joelostblom I updated my example.